# Powershell - Store function output in variable not working

Tags: function, powershell, loops

stuck at this one trying to store function output in a variable:

```
function AD-prompt($Text)
{
do
{
$in = read-host -prompt "$Text"
}
while($in -eq "")
}
```

calling the function with

```
$type = AD-prompt "Sample Text"
```

does not store anything in $type - only when i remove the entire do-while loop it works. it seems the function output is empty as the read-host output is stored in the $in variable, but i have no idea how to solve this - i didnt find another way to loop the read-host aswell sadly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return `$in` from your function by outputting it. You can do this by putting it on a line on its own after your loop:

```
function AD-prompt($Text)
{
    do
    {
       $in = read-host -prompt "$Text"
    }
    while($in -eq "")

    $in
}
```

Comment: You have to do this, OP, because your Function `AD-Prompt` didn't actually return anything.  You were storing output in the `$in` variable, but not outputting that back.  Due to variable scoping, the value of the variable goes away when the function exits.

Comment: Doesn't `$in` also stop existing outside of the loop? @FoxDeploy

Comment: Just a point of improvement, I'd use the `Do { ... } Until ($in)` construct

Comment: i thought it was such a simple mistake - thanks, i guess when i dont store the read-host output in a variable it turns the output into the function output?

Comment: Yes anything not output explicitly to anything else (such as a variable or as input to another function/cmdlet) will get returned.